# How to replace the NaT with the immediate next time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` as follows:

```
           start       values
0   2019-05-03 00:00:00 62.6
1   2019-05-03 00:15:00 62.6
2   2019-05-03 00:30:00 62.2
3   2019-05-03 00:45:00 62.9
4   2019-05-03 01:00:00 63.2
```

The `start` column has a time series with a gap of 15mins

when I do:

```
df['end'] = df['start'].shift(-1)

df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

df['start'] = df['start'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
df['end'] = df['end'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

It gives me the following output:

```
start   values  end
201905030000    62.6    201905030015
201905030015    62.6    201905030030
201905030030    62.2    201905030045
201905030045    62.9    201905030100
201905030100    63.2     NaT
```

I want to replace the `NaT` with the next immediate date value which is `201905030115` (2019-05-03 01:15)

Is there a way to do it?

**Expected Output**

```
start   values  end
201905030000    62.6    201905030015
201905030015    62.6    201905030030
201905030030    62.2    201905030045
201905030045    62.9    201905030100
201905030100    63.2    201905030115
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`pandas.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html):

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = df['start'] + df['start'].diff().bfill()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                start  values                 end
0 2019-05-03 00:00:00    62.6 2019-05-03 00:15:00
1 2019-05-03 00:15:00    62.6 2019-05-03 00:30:00
2 2019-05-03 00:30:00    62.2 2019-05-03 00:45:00
3 2019-05-03 00:45:00    62.9 2019-05-03 01:00:00
4 2019-05-03 01:00:00    63.2 2019-05-03 01:15:00
```